# The values of int fmt in format()

Tags: c++, printing, outputstream, opencv3.0

Currently using OpenCV3, but in OpenCV2, there was a way to format matrix outputs. It is used in a tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#output-formatting).

The format function seems to have changed from format(mat, str) in OpenCV2 to format(mat, int) OpenCV3. Making this call:

```
cout << "4x4: " << endl << format(fourByFour, "python") << endl;
```

yields the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]      
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:371:16: note: initializing argument 2 of ‘cv::Ptr<cv::Formatted>cv::format(cv::InputArray, int)Ptr<Formatted> format(InputArray mtx, int fmt)
```

I can plug in ints to get random printing formats, but I assume that in OpenCV3, the int fmt is meant to be some sort of "CV_" macro, but I can't seem to find that in any documentation, nor in [operations.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp).

Would anyone happen to know the proper values for fmt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked at the code on GitHub, and it seems that the constant you are looking for is `cv::Formatter::FMT_PYTHON`. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/b46719b0931b256ab68d5f833b8fadd83737ddd1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp#L2855).